# How to add a Unit of Time which is equal to 'Days' to a "leave" calculated column which states "yes" or "no" for if someone is on leave?

Tags: workday-api

I have created a calculated column called "Leave" which states whether an employee is on leave or not, by stating "Yes" or "No".

I would like to add additional criteria to this field which states that the unit of "leave" time is equal to 'Days' and that units requested is greater than or equal to 20.

Therefore the "Leave" calculated field should only flag individuals that have 20 days or more leave.

What function makes this possible to do in Workday reporting?

I've asked the workday community

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Date Difference function to calculate the days between two dates and then a True False to compare the output of days.